# Change the legend on the color key of Heat Map in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I have created the heatmap in R using HeatMaps.2. Everything went fine except the color key in my figure.

I'm plotting the expression values of genes in '`control`' and '`case`' conditions. In the final heatmap all upregualted genes have '`Red`' in the '`case`' condition and the downregulated genes have '`Green`' in the '`case`' condition which is perfect. But looking at the color key, Red shows low values and green shows high values.

In the legend of the color key, the value range is from `20-100` and the colors transitioning from '`red`' to '`green`'. I don't know how the Value's are calculated as my data has the values only from `2.0 - 13.0`. This is how my code looks like:

```
 my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "green"), (n=100))

 heatmap.2(mat_data, Rowv=F, Colv=F, trace="none", dendrogram="none",     density.info="none", key=TRUE,col=my_palette,  
      notecol="black",cexRow=0.45, cexCol=0.75,
      offsetCol=0.5, symm=F,symkey=F, scale="none")
```

Could someone let me know how exactly these values are calculated and how can i invert these values to show '`red`' high and '`green`' low values?

Comment: probably because you have n=100?

Comment: i changed the value of 'n' but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use `ggplot`.

```
# Package
require(ggplot)

# Sample data
mat_data = data.frame(x = rep(1:3,3), y = rep(1:3, each = 3), value = 1:9);

# Plot using ggplot
p <- ggplot(data = mat_data) +                        # Set data
  geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) +        # Define variables to plot
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green")    # Set colour scheme

# Display plot
p
```

See [here](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/) for more a more detailed example.

Output from example:

[image]